# Trying to get information user_friends, user_events, user_managed groups via Facebook Graph API but getting an error message

Tags: facebook-graph-api

To start off, sorry, I'm pretty new at this!

I'm an assistant research coordinator at an university, and we've been using Facebook groups to conduct studies. I've been using a set of instructions created by my former colleagues (who have now left) on how to download my Facebook group data (such as comments and posts). It was working fine before, but today, when I was trying to download the information, it has not worked.

Instead, I get this:

```
{ 
  "error":{
    "message": "Unsupported get request. Object with ID '2016101665345495' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
    "type": "GraphMethodException",
    "code": 100,
    "error_subcode": 33,
    "fbtrace_id": "ASWzpxRukCz"
  }
}
```

I suspect it is related to Facebook's new policy on April 4th: "Beginning April 4, 2018, all apps, including those formerly approved, must undergo App Review in order to retain or gain access to the Groups API. For apps currently using the API, review is required once App Review resumes or access will be removed."

I'm a little confused because we're not using an app so I don't understand what kind of permissions could be missing.

Comment: _“I'm a little confused because we're not using an app”_ - if you are using the API, then you are using an app ... because that is simply one of the prerequisites for using the API to begin with.

Comment: Hi @Cbroe, thanks for responding! Sorry, need to clarify: yes, we're using the API but this belongs to Facebook. So if they want us to submit for Login Review, I don't know what to submit to get permission. Would you happen to know?

Comment: App review has been in place for quite a while now - but in light of current events, they are giving the whole system a do-over. You might not be able to submit for review immediately though, quote: _"review is required once App Review resumes"_ https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review

Answer (score 1):

All the information you need can be found here: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/04/04/facebook-api-platform-product-changes

Access to the Group API is not possible at all right now.

You should also take a look at this link: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes#4-4-2018

Comment: Hi! Thanks for commenting. Facebook is asking us to submit our app for Login Review. However, the app that we've been using belongs to Facebook. Thus, I don't know exactly what to submit to get permission. Would you happen to know?

Comment: i don´t understand...in your title, you state that you are using the graph api and some permissions. you MUST have an app for that. you cannot use the graph api without an app.

Comment: either way, access to groups is not possible at all at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

**Beginning April 4, 2018, all apps, including those formerly approved, must undergo App Review in order to gain access to the Events API, Groups API, and Pages API. Apps accessing the Events API and Groups API will lose access and require review once App Review resumes. For apps using Pages API, review will be required once App Review resumes or access will be removed.**

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review